# Cannot install R packages on a Mac

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install packages (ANY!) in R on a Mac but it always gives me the same error:

`Error in install.packages : type 'binary' is not supported on this platform`

I have also tried using:

`> install.packages("ggplot2_3.3.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source") Warning: invalid package ‘ggplot2_3.3.3.tar.gz’ Error: ERROR: no packages specified Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘ggplot2_3.3.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status`

Did not have this problem before.

Can someone help me out please?

Thanks

Valentina

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("ggplot2")` ?

Comment: Yes, same error...

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("ggplot2", type = "source")`? How did you install R? What is your R version? What is your Mac OS version?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, yes exactly...I made a confusion with R and Rstudio installed in the conda environments and the standalone versions. This problem is fixed when I install the packages directly from the anaconda-navigator.